# In any field, does $c$ is a root of a polynomial $ f(x) ∈ F[x]$ implies that $f(x)=(x-c)g(x)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory, roots

I know the statement holds in the field **R** and **C**

But for any other fields, does it hold in general? If so, how can I formally prove that. Also I think there is something related to zero divisors, if any, in the ring  $F[x]$. It seems subtle...

Could some one **formally** prove or give me some counterexample of the statement? And could someone point out if there exist some subtle relation to the zero divisors in $F[x]$?

Many thanks?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2593642/fr-0-for-r-in-r-implies-that-x-r-divides-fx/2593666#2593666

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is because the ring of polynomials with coefficients in a field is a euclidean domain under the degree function. In other words $f(x)=(x-\alpha)g(x)+b$, with $b\in F$.

Cleary $(x-\alpha$ divides $f(x)$ if and only if $b=0$ if and only if $f(\alpha)=0$