# $f(r)=0$ for $r\in R$ implies that $x-r$ divides $f(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $f\in R[x]$ be such that $f(r)=0$ for some $r\in R$. I wonder if $x-r$ divides $f(x)$ in this case.

I know this is true when $R$ is an Euclidean domain, since we can write $f(x)=(x-r)g(x)+c$. But is this true for a more general commutative ring $R$?

Plus, if this is false, is there a condition on $R$ weaker than the Euclidean domain that makes this true (PID, UFD)?

Answer (score 5):

Just realize that $f(x)-f(r)$ is a linear combination of $x^k-r^k$'s and $x-r$ divides every $x^k-r^k$.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, over any commutative ring, if $m$ is a **monic** polynomial then
for each $f$ there is a unique $q$ with $f-qm$ having degree less than
that of $m$. Here for $m(x)=x-r$ you get $f(x)=(x-r)q(x)+c$ and $c$
must be $f(r)$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is true and can be stated slightly more abstractly.  Here's a proof that doesn't use the division algorithm.

**Lemma.**
*Let $R$ be a unital commutative ring and $R[x]$ be the one-variable polynomial ring over $R$.  For $\alpha \in R$, let
\begin{align*}
\varphi = \text{eval}_\alpha: R[x] &\to R\\
x &\mapsto \alpha
\end{align*}
be the evaluation homomorphism.  Then $\ker(\varphi) = (x-\alpha)$ and the induced map $\overline{\varphi}: R[x]/(x-\alpha) \to R$ is an isomorphism.*

Note that $\ker(\varphi) = \{f \in R[x] : f(\alpha) = 0\}$.

*Proof*.  Certainly $(x - \alpha) \subseteq \ker(\varphi)$, so it remains to show the reverse inclusion.  Given $f = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^i \in \ker(\varphi)$, then
$$
0 = f(\alpha) = \sum_i a_i \alpha^i \, .
$$
We can rewrite $f$ as a polynomial in $x-\alpha$ by writing $x = (x - \alpha) + \alpha$ and using the binomial theorem:
\begin{align*}
f &= \sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^i = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i ((x - \alpha) + \alpha)^i = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i \sum_{j = 0}^i \binom{i}{j} (x-\alpha)^j \alpha^{i-j}\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^n a_i \sum_{j = 0}^n \binom{i}{j} (x-\alpha)^j \alpha^{i-j} = \sum_{j = 0}^n \underbrace{\left(\sum_{i=0}^n a_i  \binom{i}{j} \alpha^{i-j}\right)}_{b_j} (x-\alpha)^j = \sum_{j=0}^n b_j (x - \alpha)^j
\end{align*}

(Note that $\binom{i}{j} = 0$ for $j > i$, which allows us to change the upper limit of the inner sum from $i$ to $n$.)  Since $f(\alpha) = 0$, then
$$
b_0 = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i \binom{i}{0} \alpha^{i-0} = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i \alpha^i = f(\alpha) = 0 \, .
$$
Since $b_0 = 0$, then every term in $f = \sum_{j=0}^n b_j (x - \alpha)^j$ has a factor of $x - \alpha$, so $f \in (x - \alpha)$.

This idea also works in multivariable polynomial rings; see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1854706/22912) for the proof.

Comment: I guess writing $x = (x - \alpha) + \alpha$ can be seen as a sort of trivial application of the division algorithm.